# Error occued during server update. libklibc error

Tags: 16.04, server, package-management, dependencies

I am using Ubuntu Server 16.04 and am getting the following error while updating the system (`sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y`):

```
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.  
The following packages have unmet dependencies: 
klibc-utils : Depends:
              libklibc (= 2.0.4-8ubuntu1.16.04.4) but 2.0.4-8ubuntu1.16.04.3 is installed  
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

After running `sudo apt -f install` I got the following error:

> pkg: error processing archive
>   /var/cache/apt/archives/libklibc_2.0.4-8ubuntu1.16.04.4_amd64.deb
>   (--unpack): unable to create
>   '/lib/klibc-k3La8MUnuzHQ0_kG8hokcGAC0PA.so.dpkg-new' (while processing
>   './lib/klibc-k3La8MUnuzHQ0_kG8hokcGAC0PA.so'): Permission denied
>   Errors were encountered while processing:
>   /var/cache/apt/archives/libklibc_2.0.4-8ubuntu1.16.04.4_amd64.deb E:
>   Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

I cannot manually rename/move file "klibc-k3La8MUnuzHQ0_kG8hokcGAC0PA.so" present in /lib directory

```
root@xxxxx:/lib# mv klibc-k3La8MUnuzHQ0_kG8hokcGAC0PA.so klibc-k3La8MUnuzHQ0_kG8hokcGAC0PA.so_bak   
mv: cannot move 'klibc-k3La8MUnuzHQ0_kG8hokcGAC0PA.so'  
  to 'klibc-k3La8MUnuzHQ0_kG8hokcGAC0PA.so_bak': Permission denied
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by removing the immutable flag on /lib

```
chattr -i /lib
rm /lib/klibc-xyzfile
apt-get -f install
```

then it all worked fine.